# best language for creating private blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, private

I am not being able to figure out, which lang is best for creating a private blockchain?

Comment: What do you want to do with your private blockchain? You can always create a new Ethereum blockchain without coding a single line.

Comment: This is off-topic any language should be good enough if you are a capable programmer. Bitcoin, Litecoin, Dogecoin are written in C++ (there are other implementations in Rust y Java), Ethereum has implementation in Go, Rust, Java and C++. Other blockchains has implementations in Javascript, Python, Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Wherever language you want. I made this code in Python by myself:

https://github.com/Grana69/GranaBlockChain

Its simple but was written with a Blockchain logic.

Comment: Much nice example

Comment: I tried your code,I don't know any python but there was some typo related to print and not encoding utf-8 string before hashing. https://pastebin.com/cxQhSY7k  Im not sure how it work exactly. Any way to loop it? Can you explain how and why it return true and false at the end?